# What happens when a copy of shared_ptr is made?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I want to understand how the reference count of the managed object in a `shared_ptr` is affected when a `shared_ptr` is assigned to another.

I came across the following statement in **C++ primer, 5th edition**, that:

> For example, the counter associated with a shared_ptr is incremented
>   when ... **we use it as the right-hand operand of an assignment**...
>   The **counter is decremented when we assign a new value to the
>   shared_ptr**...

As an example its shown there:

```
auto p = make_shared<int>(42); // object to which p points has one user

auto q(p); // p and q point to the same object
           // object to which p and q point has two users

auto r = make_shared<int>(42); // int to which r points has one user
r = q; // assign to r, making it point to a different address
       // increase the use count for the object to which q points
       // reduce the use count of the object to which r had pointed
       // the object r had pointed to has no users; that object is automatically freed
```

When I run a similar code, the above is not my observation:

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>

int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<int> sh1 = std::make_shared<int>(1);
  std::shared_ptr<int> sh2 = std::make_shared<int>(2);

  sh2 = sh1;

  std::cout << "sh1 use count: " << sh1.use_count() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "sh2 use count: " << sh2.use_count() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

> **Output**:
>
> sh1 use count: 2
>
> sh2 use count: 2

How can the `use_count` of `sh2` also 2? Should not it be 0 as per the mentioned text above? Am I missing something here?

Comment: `sh2 = sh1` - the previous data of `sh2` is released (and disposed of because it's reference count falls to zero), then after assignment `sh2` and `sh1` both reference the same data (and thus the reference count for both is likewise the same: 2; if it wasn't, shared_ptr would be utterly worthless).

Comment: Try printing out the wrapped pointer of both `sh1` and `sh2`, and it should be obvious.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : Yes, u r right. The managed addresses (from `get()`)of both sh1 and sh2 are same post assignment, i.e. they are pointing to same managed element.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At first you had `sh1.use_count=1` and `sh2.use_count=1`. Now when you assign using `sh2=sh1`, this is what happens:

1. The `sh2` counter is decreased by one, because `sh2` (the `shared_ptr`) is going to take another pointer
2. Since `sh2.use_count=0` now, the object under its pointer, which is `int(2)` is destroyed.
3. Now you assigned `sh2` to a new object, which belongs to `sh1`, and hence its counter is increased by one, so: `sh2.use_count=2`, and of course also `sh1.use_count=2`, because both `shared_ptr` objects point to the same object, which is the `int(1)`.

Answer (score 3):

I think this misunderstanding occurs because you think that counter is stored in `shared_ptr` instance along with a pointer to an owned object. However in reality an instance of `shared_ptr` contains only a pointer to an internal storage object that contains both reference counter and a pointer to an owned object. Therefore when you perform `sh2 = sh1;` assignment you make `sh2` refer to the same internal storage object as `sh1` so the counters value reported by both `sh1` and `sh2` is taken from the same source.

Answer (score 0):

Originally we have

```
sh1.use_count =1 and 
sh2.use_count = 1
*sh1  = 1 and 
*sh2  = 2
```

After `sh2 = sh1`. Both `sh1 ->int(1) <- sh2`.

What happen to `int(2)`? 
It got destroyed as the `sh2` now points to `int(1)`.

Hence, we have

```
sh1.use_count == sh2.use_count
*sh1 == *sh2
```

*sh1 and *sh2 have 1